# How to get Altair to sort the y axis based on specified field?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, graph, altair

Can anyone help me figure out how to get my y axis sorted by a field in my dataset?
See code below. I want to sort the y axis which is a string concat field of ADP (a decimal number) and a NFL player name. I want to sort this y axis by the ADP which is a field called "OWNER Player ADP" which i cast as a float once it goes into the pandas dataframe. (I wanted it to be a number with a decimal point)
I also created a field called ADP which is pretty much the same thing but it is a varchar when it enters the pandas dataframe. In either case, I can't seem to get the graph to sort the y axis on either of these two variations of fields... I'm also attaching two screenshots of the current output so you can see the data output and chart output. You can see that Aaron Rodgers is at the top of the list, however he has an ADP of 48.3 . I want the player with the lowest number ADP to be at the top of the list...

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
from main.views import sql_to_dataframe
#--get draft history for a specifc owner, league, and draft type
query ="""
SELECT draft_type,season,"Player Name","Player Team"
,count(*) "Times Drafted"
,cast(round(cast(SUM(pick_no) AS DECIMAL)/cast(COUNT(DISTINCT draft_id) AS DECIMAL),1) as varchar) "OWNER Player ADP"
,cast(round(cast(SUM(pick_no) AS DECIMAL)/cast(COUNT(DISTINCT draft_id) AS DECIMAL),1) as varchar) "ADP"
,concat(cast(round(cast(SUM(pick_no) AS DECIMAL)/cast(COUNT(DISTINCT draft_id) AS DECIMAL),1) as varchar),' ',"Player Team") "Player ADP"
,1 "x_axis"
FROM
mytable
GROUP BY draft_type,season,draft_type,"Player Name","Player Team"
"""
source = sql_to_dataframe(query)
source['OWNER Player ADP'] = source['OWNER Player ADP'].astype(float)
print(source.head())
base=alt.Chart(
    source,
    title="Player Average Draft Position"
).encode(
    x=alt.X('x_axis:O')
    ,y=alt.Y('Player ADP:O',sort=alt.EncodingSortField(field="OWNER Player ADP:O",order ='descending', op='min'))
    #,tooltip=['Player Team','OWNER Player ADP:O']
)
bar=base.mark_square(size=300).encode(
    color=alt.Color('Times Drafted:Q', scale=alt.Scale(scheme="darkred"))#,domain=[5,0])
    ,tooltip=['Player Team','OWNER Player ADP:O','Times Drafted:N']
)

# Configure text
text = base.mark_text(baseline='middle',color='white').encode(

    text='Times Drafted:O'
    ,tooltip=['Player Team','OWNER Player ADP:O','Times Drafted:N']
)

(bar+text).properties(width=50)#.interactive()
```

[image: DataFrame and output1]

[image: Output2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`alt.EncodingSortField` does not require type codes, and does not parse them out of the input. Instead of

```
alt.EncodingSortField(field="OWNER Player ADP:O", ...)
```

use

```
alt.EncodingSortField(field="OWNER Player ADP", ...)
```

Comment: DOH! what a face palm moment that was for me. Thanks again >_<